# Comparing an emdash (—) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-escape-characters

The emdash is in the HTML from the beginning and is put in there using its escape code `&mdash;`

I need to be able to call jquery's `$("#element").text()` function and detect whether the element's text is still equal to the emdash. I have tried:

```
if($("#element").text() == "&mdash;")
```

and

```
if($("#element").text() == "—")
```

both return false when the emdash is actually the text of the element though. When I use `console.log()` the actual emdash character (the second example) gets printed, but despite that both statements return false.

How can I produce a statement that returns true when it actually is an emdash?

Comment: Please check `console.log(JSON.stringify($("#element").text()))`. I suspect spaces around the dash.

Comment: Works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/t16b7khb/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6w2j9p9t/ proves it works fine; I suspect white space, too. In that case, use indexOf https://jsfiddle.net/6w2j9p9t/1/, or trim the value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks for all your comments guys, they helped me find the correct solution.

The problem was brackets (the text editor I was using) doesn't support the emdash character so I wrote the if statement in another editor and it worked fine.