# hyphen character comparison with &mdash;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-escape-characters

I am trying to compare — with "-" but always getting false.

Referred this question : [Comparing an emdash (—) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504979/comparing-an-emdash-in-javascript)

Tried the jsfiddle link in the comment : https://jsfiddle.net/t16b7khb/. It works fine, but when i tried creating a new fiddle found that the hyphen i am entering is smaller than the one available in this jsfiddle. Not sure, whether the problem is with the OS, i am using macOS.

I have created a new fiddle by copy pasting the first 'if' from the comment and the second 'if' is typed by myself.
jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/RajKumari_1/6n7pb5uh/

```
if( $("#element").text() == "—" ) {
    console.log('works for me')
}
if( $("#element").text() == "-" ) {
    console.log('not working for me')
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The em dash (—), en dash (–) and hyphen (-) characters are *different characters* with [*different meanings*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0002.html).

Comment: Thanks, for the link found it useful.@Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `sensitivity: 'base'`

```
if( $("#element").text().localeCompare('-', 'en', {sensitivity: 'base'}) ) {
    console.log('works for me')
}
```

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/835auydp/)**