# Check if element text is `&ndash`

Tags: jquery

I want to check if selected element contains n-dash only:

```
<p>&ndash;</p>
```

But jQuery does not compare it this way:

```
$('p').text()=="-"
$('p').html()=="-"
$('p').text()=="&ndash;"
$('p').html()=="&ndash;"
```

All above is false.

Comment: `$('p').text()=="&ndash"`. Your HTML doesn't have the `;` but your JS is testing for one.

Comment: With the `;` in the HTML you can use either `.html()=="–"` or `.text()=="–"`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841824/hyphen-character-comparison-with-mdash

Comment: It has `;`, was just a typo.

Comment: The my second comment applies. https://jsfiddle.net/rxyngfcj/. Also note that in my example I test for the actual en dash (U+2013 : EN DASH), however in your example you're testing for a different character, the hyphen (U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen, dash; minus sign})

Comment: Check it text === "\u2013"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm

```js
let selector = $('p:contains("\u2013")');

if (selector.length) {
  console.log('got it !');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>&ndash;</p>
```